# Convert range to address in excel formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In the portion of formula, I have something like below.

```
MATCH(TRUE, $B3:$B$28 < 0, 0)
```

I would like to convert into Row(), column()  and tried the following

```
MATCH(TRUE,INDIRECT("B" & ROW() & ":B28") < 0, 0)
```

But the output of the formula is not the same. Could you please help to fix the formula? Thanks

Comment: Can you add some sample data showing where you are now, and where you want to be after getting your question answered?  Hard to imagine your question with just a numeric range of Excel cells.

Comment: Hi, Basically my formula is so big and I am able get it correct with the MATCH(TRUE, $B3:$B$28 < 0, 0) approach. All i wanted his make the range based on row(). since I am generating the excel sheet using program, I cannot manually drag the formula, which will automatically change the formula to MATCH(TRUE, $B4:$B$28 < 0, 0), MATCH(TRUE, $B5:$B$28 < 0, 0).. and so on MATCH(TRUE, $B28:$B$28 < 0, 0).  Instead I would like to change the range something like "B" & Row() & ":B28". So when I programatically generate the the formula is applied correctly based on the row. Thanks

Comment: Can you create a helper column with just the formula ROW() and then reference that column such as MATCH(TRUE,INDIRECT("B" & HelperColumn & ":B28") < 0, 0)?

Comment: @rwilson so Match(true,Indirect("B" & Row() & ":B28")) will not work?

Comment: @rwilson Thanks. Let me try to work out a simple workbook and upload. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can wrap `INDIRECT` function inside `INDEX` as

```
=MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(INDIRECT("B" & ROW() & ":B28"),0,0) < 0, 0)
```

This is an array formula so commit it by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Comment: Yes, before I saw your reply, I did something similar and able to fix it.  I will still accept your answer, so other forum users can use your solution.

Answer (score 2):

You should wrap `ROW()` formula with `SUM formula`. that way your `ROW()` formula will transfer from array to number and will be used with other parts of formula making valid reference for indirect. please try formula below. `=MATCH(TRUE,INDIRECT("B" & SUM(ROW()) & ":B28")<0,0)`.